# How to restrict only GSuit user to signup/in?

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-signin, google-console-developer

I am using **react-google-login** for my react app. Here is my code

```
    <GoogleLogin
    clientId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    buttonText="Google"
    render={renderProps => (
    <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} className='google-login-button'>
    <img src={GoogleButton}/>
    </button>
    )}
    onSuccess={this.googleResponse}
    onFailure={() => console.log('error')}
/>
```

What I want is, Only the Gsuit users will be able to signin/up.
Like someone with Gmail should not get the access.

Comment: Hey Rony, do you mean people without Gmail should not get access if that's the case then you will need to edit the question

Comment: No, I mean there are two type of gmail user. one is general gmail user Like xxxx@gmail.com, But there is Gsuit user. I want only the gsuit users to login

Answer (score 0):

You can try out with hostedDomain props of GoogleLogin if not tried yet. I found this relevant [Restrict access to google login](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/issues/274).  Or you can follow this thread bhai.[Gsuit Restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984997/only-allow-google-sign-in-with-g-suite-accounts)